# How to fix ASP.Net Core 404 error on IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404

I have been working of a .net core project for weeks, using git, and two weeks ago I added a testing project to the solution (xunit) and for some reasons (I have no idea if the testing project is related in any way to my problem) when I run the api with ISS I get a not found (not a .net error, google's one, see the screenshot below), on chrome (automatically opened with url by ISS & VS) and on postman ... The project always worked, but it does not anymore. I have pulled older branches that I am 100% sure they were working before.

I know it's not a lot of information but I literally have no idea what to start with, so please ask me for any additionnal information.

**I also noticed this in the output when running the solution :**

1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware:Warning: Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
2. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 30.0135ms 200
3. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 210.0354ms 404

**I have tried :**

- Deleting the solution on local, git pull it again
- Checking out a local older branch that I'm 100% sure was working before
- Closing VS / opening again
- dotnet dev-certs https --trust

[image]

error on screenshots means No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:59490 
I'm pretty sure my project was working with https before but now the url iis gives me is using http ...

Here is my launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59490/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59492/"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you show your launchSettings.json. It should be in the properties of your solution.

Comment: Just edited my question @PatrickMcvay

Comment: Sorry I had to put that as an answer because Urls are buggy in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the launchSettings.json file has bugged out and is no longer correct. Create a new project with the exact same settings as your other project and copy that launchSettings.json over to your project. You will need to change the application name to your project's name.

Comment: with sslPort in iisSettings = 44388 this still gives me not found, but i get something else with sslPort = 0, i get localhost does not allow connection ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: If you made the changes while IIS Express was still running, you will have to manually exit IIS Express and restart it, and port 0 is not a valid port for communicating between hosts so it will error out.

Comment: alright thanks for that, just changed it back to 44388, still the same issue :D

Comment: so, with the launchUrl as "https:// localhost:44388/" and the sslPort as 44388 you are still getting a not found result?

Comment: yes unfortunally ... i have put exactly what's inside your answerr and still get the 404 error

Comment: Okay, how are you implementing your https? Are you using the [RequireHttps] annotation in your controllers?

Comment: nothing at all, i just have app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in my startup.cs (that was there before, i did not put it myself, and it was working before while it was here so i doubt that's the problem, and i tried commenting it anyway and it doesn't change anything. But i'm confused because on my postman i see my routes that were working before and they are all with https ... and now iis opens only http

Comment: i just clicked the "configure for https" thing when I created the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210181/discussion-between-patrick-mcvay-and-max).